# Не понимаю, как огласить такой класс. C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Нашёл в какой-то старой книжке задачки/упражнения по c++, решил порешать чуть-чуть, вот задачка:

"Тип «Дата» определяется как класс, содержащий закрытые числовые поля с днем, месяцем, годом.
Тип «Подключение» определить как класс, содержащий:
реализуемое в виде символьной строки произвольной длины закрытое поле с названием сети и числовое поле, определяющее наличие льготы;"
Не понимаю, как реализовать второй класс("Подключение").
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
class date{
    private:
        void set_day(std::string date_day)
        {
            day = date_day;
        }
        void set_month(std::string date_month)
        {
            day = date_month;
        }
        void set_year(std::string date_year)
        {
            day = date_year;
        }
};
class connect{
    
};
int main() {
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что ж, возьмемся за *оглашенные* классы...

У вас первый класс не доделан. В нем так и нет требуемых в задании *закрытых числовых полей с днем, месяцем, годом*.

```
class Date
{
    private:
        int day_, month_, year_;
```

По заданию это главное... Ну, а дальше можно добавить всякие

```
    Date(int year, int month, int day):year_(year),month_(month),day_(day){}

    int  day() const { return d; }
    void day(int d)  { day_ = d; }
```

Ну, и прочие...

Второй, по аналогии:

> реализуемое в виде символьной строки произвольной длины закрытое поле с названием сети и числовое поле, определяющее наличие льготы;

```
class Connect {
    private:
    string net_name;
    double privileges;
```

Остальное, думаю, допишете по аналогии?